# Executing commands from process substitution in xinitrc

Tags: bash, process-substitution, xinit

I felt that an `.xinitrc` like this

```
#!/bin/sh

bash <(sed -n 'H
    /^exec ./{
    x
    s/\([^\n]\+ &\n\)*exec .*//
    p
    }' /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc)

xmonad &
# ...
exec xterm
```

where the standard `xinitrc` minus the last bit is executed
first, would be cleaner than one where the standard file (minus
the last bit) is simply copied.  But, for some reason, it
doesn't work.  With it, `startx` doesn't leave the console.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are trying to use a process substitution with `/bin/sh` (evident from the `#!`-line), which does not support these.  Use a shell, such as `bash` or `zsh`, that knows how to do process substitutions.

The other way to do this, which may be more robust, is to make your own `~/.xinitrc` file by copying the system's version, and then change that.

Comment: my `/bin/sh` is linked to bash, but perhaps xinit uses something else.  if so, the first line (which is also in the file in `/etc`) seems inappropriate

Comment: @Toothrot When `bash` is started as `sh`, it runs in its POSIX compatibility mode in which process substitutions are not recognised.

Comment: oh!  that explains it then.  thanks.